# Plotly express imshow slider crash

Tags: python, image, plotly, visualization

I am trying to use imshow from plotly express with its built-in slider (like [here](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/#exploring-3d-images-and-timeseries-with-animationframe)).

However, when I move the slider (quite quickly) back and forth, it moves out of the plot *div*:

Demo image:
[image]

Demo gif:
[image: gif]

Code to reproduce `(numpy==1.20.1, plotly==4.14.3)`:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

img = np.random.rand(50, 512, 512)
fig = px.imshow(img, 
                animation_frame=0,
                binary_string=True,
                width=500, height=500, 
                labels=dict(animation_frame="slice"))
fig.show()
```

Does anyone has any idea why this might happen?

Comment: I can't reproduce that effect myself. Does it actually crash? It hasn't seemed to in the information you've given.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am very surprised that you could not reproduce that issue. I provided a gif of my crash behavior.

Comment: I've had another go and made it do that once, very briefly, in quite a long time of trying. It's not a crash though, that's not the right term. Some kind of layout glitch. Does it happen if you make the window larger? Feels like it might be something briefly expanding width-wise and being pushed down by some kind of wrapping behaviour. It's not really my area of expertise to figure out properly though.

Comment: It happened on larger windows aswell. It found a workaround by using a slider from Dash Core Components and plotting the images one by one.